# Best way for MySQL table history and snapshots

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing a CRM in Laravel 7 with MySQL. In it I have orders that have a customer.
I want to do 2 things:

1. Have the order always point to customer data from where it was created
2. Store the history of customers info (from customers table)

In the past, I have used _history table with the same structure of the original one, _snapshot table with only the changes (ex: id_snapshot, id_customer, column, value, date), snapshots of the data (like customer data) in json format in mysql.

But I don't know what is the best scalable solution.

Comment: The requirements are a bit vague. If for example you only need this information for auditing purposes then even a daily DB dump might be enough but if you make active use of historic data then a _history solution might be necessary. It's all about specific use case as there's always a lower bound of what can be done based on your requirements.

Comment: I need to be able to see the order with the data from when it was created. For example if the customer is modified and you access an order from 1 year of that user, you will see the customer data from that time, not the updated info.

Comment: You can have a all the relevant data stored in the order table (or a set of tables relating to the order) as a "snapshot" of all relevant order information. Having a detailed history of everything might not be needed

Answer (score 0):

Basically, storing SQL for this data is probably a good way. You can imagine using a scalable MySQL instance on a cloud provider like AWS RDS.

Another possible way is to use a NoSQL database like MongoDB or Elasticsearch. It is easier to scale and particularly suitable for JSON data.

You can also use 100% SaaS services like Firebase or even store JSON data on the S3 service if performance is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this sort of an audit framework yourself using triggers a s history tables. Until recently that would have been the most sensible way. Now, however, it would amount to re-inventing the wheel since MariaDB implemented a feature called temporal tables which does this for you:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-data-tables/

It will allow you to see the data as it was at any past point in time.